# Dynamically Set Attribute in Component.Set()

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have been trying to build a generic method which can dynamically set attributes via `component.set()` for example something like:

```
for(var i=0;i<myObjectArray;++){
    component.set(myObjectArray[i].attName,myObjectArray[i].attValue);
}
```

But I get undefined errors. I've tried using "v.att" and just v.att but neither work.

Is this possible?

**Edit**

Here's the combinations I have tried.

**Single quotes:**

```
var myObjArray = [];
myObjArray.push({attName:'v.att1', attValue:object.value1});
myObjArray.push({attName:'v.att2', attValue:object.value2});
for(var  i = 0; i < myObjArray.length; i++){
    component.set(myObjArray[i].attName,response);
}
```

**Single in double:**

```
var myObjArray = [];
myObjArray.push({attName:"'v.att1'", attValue:object.value1});
myObjArray.push({attName:"'v.att2'", attValue:object.value2});
```

**Double in single:**

```
var myObjArray = [];
myObjArray.push({attName:'"v.att1"', attValue:object.value1});
myObjArray.push({attName:'"v.att2"', attValue:object.value2});
```

All end up with the error:

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'varName' of
>   undefined]

Comment: I think that should work as long as myObjectArray[i].attName contains the value provider: "v.myAttributeName". Can you provide some sample data within myObjectArray? And of course, that said attribute must exist on the page. If you want to ignore the exceptions, why not consider putting in a try-catch block?

Comment: `component.set` expects the attribute name enclosed in quotes. So that's where you may like to have the `myObjectArray[i].attName` rendered enclosed accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some stupidity on my side here. The dynamic set fails in a callback...so I was trying to refer to array which was undefined in the context of the callback.